# Jetpack compose material3 TextField minimum height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

so I have a `OutlinedTextField` with `supportingText` which is available with conditions.

```
var usernameValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .minimumInteractiveComponentSize(),
    value = usernameValue,
    onValueChange = {
        usernameValue = it
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
    colors = androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
        disabledIndicatorColor = Color.White,
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
        containerColor = Color(0xFFE5EAF0),
        placeholderColor = Color.Transparent
    ),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 12.dp),
    singleLine = true,
    isError = shouldShowUsernameError,
    supportingText = {
        if (shouldShowUsernameError)
            Text(
                userNameErrorMessage,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
            )
    }
)
```

this is the screen when there is no error
[image]

and this the screen when there is error[image]

as you can see problem is when there is error, error messages change the layout!
and the question is how can I set minimum height for `OutlinedTextField`

Comment: The layout changes because there is the supportingText. It is not clear what is the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout changes because when `shouldShowUsernameError=true` there is the `supportingText`.

To avoid it you can use something like:

```
supportingText = {
    Text(
        text = if (shouldShowUsernameError) "userNameErrorMessage" else "",
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
    )
}
```

[image]